# Showing $\Vert x \Vert_p = \Vert x \Vert_q$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ iff x has at most one nonzero element, where $p\neq q, p,q \in [1,\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis

### Problem

> Show $\Vert x \Vert_p = \Vert x \Vert_q$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ iff x has at most one nonzero element, where $p\neq q, p,q \in [1,\infty]$.

---

### Try

$(\Leftarrow)$ is trivial.

$(\Rightarrow)$

Since $\Vert x \Vert_p = \left( \sum \vert x_i \vert^p \right)^{1/p} = \left( \sum \vert x_i \vert^q \right)^{1/q} = \Vert x \Vert_q$,

$$
\sum \vert x_i \vert^p = \left( \sum \vert x_i \vert^q \right)^{p/q}
$$

but it is hard for me to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p>q$ and  $y_i=x_i/{\|x\|_q}$. Then $\|y\|_q=1$ and we get $\|y\|_p=1$ from the hypothesis. Note that $|y_i| \leq 1$ for all $i$. Hence $|y_i|^{p} \leq |y_i|^{q}$ and strict inequality holds unless $y_i=1$ or $y_i=0$. But the condition $\|y\|_q=1$ shows that $|y_i|=1$ can hold only for one value of $i$ and all other $y_j$'s are necessarily $0$. This also implies that $|x_i|=\|x\|_q$ can for one value of $i$ and all other $x_j$'s are necessarily $0$.

The case $ p<q$ is similar.